# Shopify liquid: {% assign %} two linklists to a nav

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Liquid is it possible to assign a var to combine two linklists, for example:

```
{% if section.settings.main_linklist == blank and section.settings.top_bar_linklist != blank %}
  {% assign navMobile = linklists[section.settings.top_bar_linklist] %}
{% else %}
  {% assign navMobile = linklists[section.settings.main_linklist] %}
{% endif %}
```

I want the second assign to be something like:

```
 {% assign navMobile = linklists[section.settings.main_linklist] and linklists[section.settings.top_bar_linklist] %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the links with a hook of some kind between them.

For example:

```
{% assign navMobile = section.settings.main_linklist | append: "|" | append: section.settings.top_bar_linklist %}
```

Afterwards you can split them by "|" and get yourself an array.

There is no other way to save two links in a single variable in liquid.

Comment: The `navMobile` will become a string and you won't be able to fetch the links from there anymore, no?

Comment: @Vladimir Yep your are right, only the handles should be appended, updated. Pianoc, you must use the split filter.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a concat function.
Not tested but something like that should work:

```
{% assign mobileLinks = linklists[section.settings.main_linklist] | concat: linklists[section.settings.top_bar_linklist] %}
```

Then you'll be able to loop through your new array:

```
{% for link in mobileLinks %}
    {{ link.title }}
{% endfor %}
```